# WebDeploy and Debug builds

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Our web application includes different db connections and many superflous output in debug mode, this is very helpful for local testing during development. This also means that we need to remeber to switch to Release mode before each Publish (inside VStudio).

Yesterday buy mistake we published the Debug version of the web application causing a small disaster.

What is the best approach to avoid this in future?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script the build using msbuild, or powershell and have the script specify 'Release' and then call msdeploy.  If you have a script to do the deployment instead of doing it by hand it will always be consistent.

Comment: Thanks John, do you mean creating a batch file?

Comment: @devdept: You can use a batch file or some of the tools that come built-in with Visual Studio (and Team Foundation Server if you are using it) or a third party tool. The point is that if you want to prevent the issue again you should **automate your deployment**